# InnoSetup - adding value to default subkey?

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup, regedit

How do i add default ValueData to the subkey? for example:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "(Standaard)"; ValueData: "{app}"
```

How can i make sure the value `{app}` i am adding to the default? Depending on OS language such as mine is Nederlands i have a default key (Standaard) but in English language this key can be (Default) or for other languages it maybe random.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLVED - ValueName if empty then it use the default

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company\My Program\Settings"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "{app}"
```